# getCookieValue returns an object

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I`ve used method getCookieValue() for get cookie value from session, it returns an object io.gatling.http.action.cookie.GetCookieValueBuilder@2012cf26

```
.exec{session => {
       val cookie = getCookieValue(CookieKey("CookieKey"))
          println("Session cookie is :::::::::::::::::::::::::" + cookie.toString)
         session
     }}
```

should get cookie value instead of io.gatling.http.action.cookie.GetCookieValueBuilder@2012cf26

Answer (score -1):

looking at the documentation, getCookieValue is a DSL action that (as you discovered) returns a builder, so you would need to execute it in an 'exec' block - it's designed to get a named cookie and put it into the session.

so if you did

```
.exec(getCookieValue(CookieKey("CookieKey")))
```

the value of the cookie named "CookieKey" would be put in the session under the key "CookieKey".

You can't call DSL methods inside a session function - the returned builder won't ever be called

Comment: How can I print all cookies and all heades values ? Because I don`t know what headers and cookies are in response

Comment: If you just need this for debugging, you can turn on TRACE logging and these are shown for each response.